# Как отключать клиента, если более 5% нагрузки?

Tags: freebsd

Есть пару клиентов, которые загружают крывыми скриптами. Как бы их отрубать на часик?freeBSD.

Comment: Ну а как реализован механизм пользователей?Они  привязаны к чему-то или нет?Можно ведь к пользователю привязать процесс и если этот процесс превышает допустимые нормы, то блокировать на 10-15 минут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитай `man 5 login.conf`.  Много интересной инфы по разделению ресурсов. И кого или что планируется отрубать? Если скипт, то переодически парсим вывод, например, `iostat` если `cpu<mode>` зашкаливает ищем через ps виновника и `kill (killall)`, далее могут быть варианты ....  И еще в портах есть демон `blimitd` возможно это то, что надо.

Answer (score 0):

ещё можно попробовать cpulimit

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать monit